# Same PHP, Same Server, Different Results

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I have three domains on the same server (CentOS 7.5.1804), all running WordPress 4.9.8, all running the same version of PHP (7.2.10) and using the same php.ini file (literally, not the same php.ini file copied to each directory, the exact same single file).

The problem is that on only one domain, WordPress thinks that I don't have `php-mysql` installed, yet the other two sites work without issue.

I get the following on the non-working domain:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
>   is required by WordPress.

Despite the fact that the same `php.ini` file is being used, on the non-working site, the `phpinfo()` report is missing the `mysqli` section.

Domains are: [hummdis.com](http://hummdis.com) (non-working), [dev.hummdis.com](http://dev.hummdis.com) (working), 
[exoticallyplugged.com](http://exoticallyplugged.com) (working).

Thoughts??

Comment: What operating system and version is this?

Comment: Sorry, CentOS 7.5.1804.  I've added it to the original post.

Comment: this question might be better asked at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ as it is more about server configuration than about coding.

Comment: recompile PHP with the required mysql plugin.

Comment: Given that you're running WHM, I'd probably start with reinstalling via EasyApache...

Comment: @Martin -- You're missing the point. If WordPress is working on two sites (which use MySQL) then why would it not work on the 3rd site that uses all of the exact same configuration?  Honestly, what would a recompile solve?

Comment: @joshstrike, I've already done that. No change.

Comment: Raise a support request with CPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've resolved the issue and I'm not 100% sure what fixed it.  However, these are the steps that I took:

1. `yum update`
2. This resulted in:

> Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:

I'm not going to provide the full update, the point is that I couldn't perform a Yum update because of these issues.

3. I found [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2576) and followed the steps.
4. I then found [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/centos-111/centos-yum-update-depency-problem-4175526460/) and followed the steps that install `yum plugin-priorities`.

I then tested the site and it's loading without issue.

Comment: This makes little sense though, since `yum` modifications are system-wide. They ought to work the same against all sites.

Do all the Wordpress sites use **the same database driver**? Possibly the ones that worked used a driver that *was* installed (say, mysqli), while the one that did not used the MySQL driver which wasn't, possibly due to a `yum` error.

Comment: @LSern I completely agree with you.  They all used the mysqli driver and they all used the same php.ini files.  I can't explain it either, but what I can say is that once I resolved the YUM update errors, the site was online.  The only other thing that I can think of is that the other two sites were running off of cache since they hadn't been updated and the last site, which was newly installed, exposed the problem.  Maybe the mysqli became damaged because of the failed update and it was resolved when the RPM errors were resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can conceive is that **all tests for MySQL fail**, and they do so **in all your sites**.

But on the two working sites, you have a `db.php` fixup file that makes things right. On the one that doesn't work, the WP_CONTENT_DIR has no fixup.

This is the [relevant source section](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/load.php):

```
if ( ! extension_loaded( 'mysql' ) && ! extension_loaded( 'mysqli' )
    && ! extension_loaded( 'mysqlnd' ) && ! file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) ) {
    wp_load_translations_early();
    $protocol = wp_get_server_protocol();
    header( sprintf( '%s 500 Internal Server Error', $protocol ), true, 500 );
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    die( __( 'Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.' ) );
```

As you can see, the error is only generated if all the tests fail, and there is no "db.php" to be found.

You may also want to check whether the `.htaccess` directives are the same between the sites. I seem to remember that MySQL modules may be loaded dynamically, and if so, it could be that **some sites load them, and some don't**.

Comment: The problem is that, for whatever reason, PHP is not reporting MySQL, but only for the hummdis.com domain.  The `phpinfo();` results for the other two sites show that it does report when they're all using the same `php.ini` file.  Why would PHP report 2/3 times that the `mysqli` feature is installed on only two sites if using the same `php.ini` file?

I've tried using the same `.htaccess` file from the other two sites on hummdis.com, but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Also check the apache .conf files. Where are the module loading directives? In the PHP.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing from $PATH the locations, some info. Go to commnad line of a working domain and issue:  which php-mysql
and issue the same commnad to the one that is not working.

It looks, if you use diffent linux user, in .profile to have problem